# How to set up an Antel SIM in Uruguay?

Tags: cellphones, uruguay

I bought a SIM card from an Antel shop and they said they put U$200 on it and I could go online to set up whatever else is needed. I went to the site but I'm stuck on:

> * Número de Documento:

I tried putting my passport number (what they asked for in the shop) but it says:

> La cédula no es válida

Any help?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have one, only a passport (I'm only here for 2 months)

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer is to not do this online

Comment: Try putting in 5.599.611-2 (random result from Image Search). I would also caution against putting your real data *anywhere* where you know it's impossible to verify - better to stick to fake info for security purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After getting a friend to call the help line, I found I needed to configure an Access Point Name (APN).

Go to your SIM settings, Access Point Names, new APN:

Name: vera1
APN: antel.lte
APN Type: default,supl

Then restart your phone.